# Backup Failed error processing remote manifest

Tags: software-installation, gnupg

I get the following error:

```
Error processing remote manifest (duplicity-inc.20181001T155227Z.to.20181004T170535Z.manifest.gpg): GPG Failed, see log below:
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: WARNING: "--no-use-agent" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
gpg: starting migration from earlier GnuPG versions
gpg: porting secret keys from '/home/master/.gnupg/secring.gpg' to gpg-agent
gpg: can't open '/home/master/.gnupg/secring.gpg': Permission denied
gpg: AES encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
===== End GnuPG log =====
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/954536/682358), and now everything's working. I suppose the crucial part for me was the line

```
chown -R $(whoami) ~/.gnupg/
```

; before these changes the ownership to `secring.gpg` was set to `root`.